# Can I edit gpedit.msc with a program written in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Can I edit gpedit.msc in a program made in C

I want to edit it to disable cmd and the control panel.
(I tried to edit it using the registry, but there was no entry.)

What should I do?
I use Windows 32 API.

Comment: Every file you may edit in C language. And yes -  this policies may set in registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (useful for me)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <InitGuid.h>
#include <gpedit.h>
#include <shlguid.h> // shell GUIDs
#include <shlobj.h>  // IActiveDesktop
#include <comdef.h>

HRESULT ModifyUserPolicyForPreventAccessToCmdPrompt(int iMode)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    //
    // Use IGroupPolicyObject to retrieve and modify the registry settings.
    // for the GPO represented by the gpoInfo.lpDsPath
    //
    IGroupPolicyObject* p = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGroupPolicyObject,
        (LPVOID*)&p);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //
        // The GPO value we want to modify is the
        //
        // User Configuration
        //   +> Policies
        //        +>Administrative Templates
        //            +->System
        //                 +->Prevent access to the command prompt
        //
        DWORD dwSection = GPO_SECTION_USER;
        HKEY hGPOSectionKey = NULL;
        DWORD dwData;
        HKEY hSettingKey;
        LSTATUS rStatus;
        hr = 0;
        //
        //Open the GPO and load its registy values for both: Machine and user
        //

        hr = p->OpenLocalMachineGPO(GPO_OPEN_LOAD_REGISTRY);
        //
        // Request the user Registy hive for the GPO
        //
        hr = p->GetRegistryKey(dwSection, &hGPOSectionKey);
        //
        // Determine if you want to set it to Not Congigure,
        //  Enabled or Disabled for the GPO itself.
        //
        // The second call, RequestSetting will provide the "Yes" or "No"
        // value for setting
        // the policy as shown by the GPO Editor
        //
        // iMode
        // 0=Not Configured, 1=Enabled, 2=Disabled
        //
        switch (iMode)
        {
        case 0:
            //
            // We do not want to configure the GPO, but we don't want to
            // affect other GPOs on the same key,
            // so just delete values associated with this
            // particular GPO setting.
            //
            rStatus = RegDeleteValue(hGPOSectionKey,
                L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System\\DisableCMD"
            );
            rStatus = RegDeleteValue(hGPOSectionKey,
                L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System\\**del.DisableCMD"
            );
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            //
            // To enable the policy, the DisableCMD value must
            // exist and the **del.DisableCMD value must not.
            //
            // lData:
            //
            // Check to see if the key for this policy exists. 
            // If if it does, retrieve a handle
            // If not, create it.
            //
            if (RegOpenKeyEx(hGPOSectionKey,
                L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System", 0,
                KEY_WRITE, &hSettingKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                rStatus = RegCreateKeyEx(
                    hGPOSectionKey,
                    L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System",
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                    KEY_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    &hSettingKey,
                    NULL);
            }
            //
            // Set the value DisableCMD and allow, disallow
            // script launching of CMD 
            //
            DWORD lData = 1;
            rStatus = RegSetValueEx(hSettingKey, L"DisableCMD",
                NULL, REG_DWORD, (BYTE *)(&lData),
                sizeof(DWORD));
            //
            // Remove the not configured value indicator from the hive.
            // It may not exist, so the RegDeleteValue may return
            // and error, this can be ignored.
            //
            rStatus = RegDeleteValue(hGPOSectionKey,
             L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System\\**del.DisableCMD"
            );
            rStatus = RegCloseKey(hSettingKey);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            //
            // Disable the policy.
            // must remove the DisableCMD value and add the
            //  **del.DisableCMD value.
            //
            // Same stesp as before, check to see if the key for this
            // policy exists,
            // if not, create it.
            //
            BOOL bCreate = FALSE;
            if (RegOpenKeyEx(hGPOSectionKey, L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System", 0, KEY_WRITE, &hSettingKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                rStatus = RegCreateKeyEx(
                    hGPOSectionKey,
                    L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System",
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                    KEY_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    &hSettingKey,
                    NULL);
                bCreate = TRUE;
            }
            DWORD dwType = 0;
            DWORD cbType = sizeof(dwData);
            if (!bCreate)
            {
                //
                // If we did not create the key, then our value
                //  *may* exist.
                // try to read it.  If we succeed, write that value back
                //  to **del.DisableCMD
                // if not, then set **del.DisableCMD to 0
                //
                rStatus = RegGetValue(hGPOSectionKey,
                    L"Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\System", L"DisableCMD", RRF_RT_ANY, &dwType, (BYTE *)(&dwData), &cbType);
                if (rStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS) dwData = 0;
                else RegDeleteValue(hSettingKey, L"DisableCMD");
                rStatus = RegSetValueEx(hSettingKey, L"**del.DisableCMD", NULL, REG_DWORD, (BYTE *)(&dwData), sizeof(DWORD));
            }
            else
            {
                //
                // The key was created, just set the **del.DisableCMD
                // value to 0
                //
                dwData = 0;
                rStatus = RegSetValueEx(hSettingKey, L"**del.DisableCMD", NULL, REG_DWORD, (BYTE *)(&dwData), sizeof(DWORD));
            }
            rStatus = RegCloseKey(hSettingKey);
        }
        }
        GUID RegistryId = REGISTRY_EXTENSION_GUID;
        GUID ThisAdminToolGuid =
            /*{ CLSID_PolicySnapinUser/* */
        {
            0x0F6B957E,
            0x509E,
            0x11D1,
            {0xA7, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x75, 0x71, 0xE3}
        };
        rStatus = RegCloseKey(hGPOSectionKey);
        //
        // Write the GPO back to the directory
        //
        hr = p->Save(
            FALSE,
            TRUE,
            &RegistryId,
            &ThisAdminToolGuid);
        hr = p->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    ModifyUserPolicyForPreventAccessToCmdPrompt(1);

    return 0;

}
```

Basically use the [Group Policy API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/Policy/group-policy-start-page?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to modify specific values in the GPO.

**Note: you need to logoff(Press Ctrl+Alt+Del and choose the option to Log off) to take effect after successful compilation.**

For more details, please refer: [how to modify a registry based policy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsadsi/2009/07/23/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy/)